# NULL in sql case when statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorting people by their age in columns with `case when` statements, so

```
select 
        case when age >= 11 and age <= 20 then name end column1 as "11-20",
        case when age >= 21 and age <= 30 then name end column2 as "21-30",
        case when age >= 31 and age <= 40 then name end column3 as "31-40"
from passenger
```

The result is something like that:

```
11-20    21-30    31-40
John     NULL     NULL
NULL     Kevin    NULL
Michael  NULL     NULL
NULL     NULL     Beckey
```

and I want output to look like:

```
11-20    21-30    31-40
John     Kevin    Beckey
Michael
```

So how do I remove NULL or move not NULL values up
I'm using MySQL

Comment: You should look into pivoting

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Some of them have built-in pivot operations, others require tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Oracle(?) answer of Gordon Lindoff, you can do it in MySQL like this:

```
select
  max(case when agegroup = '11-20' then name end) as "11-20",
  max(case when agegroup = '21-30' then name end) as "21-30",
  max(case when agegroup = '31-40' then name end) as "31-40"
from 
  (select @rownum1 := 0, @rownum2 := 0, @rownum3 := 0) v,
  (select
     case
       when Age > 10 and Age <= 20 then '11-20' 
       when Age > 20 and Age <= 30 then '21-30' 
       when Age > 30 and Age <= 40 then '31-40'
     end as agegroup,
     case
       when Age > 10 and Age <= 20 then @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 
       when Age > 20 and Age <= 30 then @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 
       when Age > 30 and Age <= 40 then @rownum3 := @rownum3 + 1
     end as seqnum,
     name
   from
     Passengers) p
group by
  seqnum
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ea1a/9

[**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45b6b/21) with the given data.

Comment: Well, I don't really mind, but I added a fiddle myself as well. :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I thought using the data given OP would be a little more easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You remove the `NULL`s by doing a `group by`.  But, you don't have a key for the `group by`.  Most databases support the `row_number()` function.  With that function you can do:

```
select max(case when agegroup = '11-20' then name end) as "11-20",
       max(case when agegroup = '21-30' then name end) as "21-30",
       max(case when agegroup = '31-40' then name end) as "31-40"
from (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by agegroup order by name) as seqnum
      from (select p.*,
                   (case when age >= 11 and age <= 20 then '11-20'
                         when age >= 21 and age <= 30 then '21-30'
                         when age >= 31 and age <= 40 then '31-40'
                    end) as agegroup
            from passenger p
           ) p
group by seqnum;
```

EDIT:

The equivalent in MySQL uses variables:

```
select max(case when agegroup = '11-20' then name end) as "11-20",
       max(case when agegroup = '21-30' then name end) as "21-30",
       max(case when agegroup = '31-40' then name end) as "31-40"
from (select p.*,
             @rn := if(agegroup = @agegroup, @rn + 1, 1) as seqnum,
             @agegroup := agegroup
      from (select p.*,
                   (case when age >= 11 and age <= 20 then '11-20'
                         when age >= 21 and age <= 30 then '21-30'
                         when age >= 31 and age <= 40 then '31-40'
                    end) as agegroup
            from passenger p
           ) p cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @agegroup := '') var
       order by agegroup
      ) p
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: I posted and deleted an answer like this, but it won't produce the desired results. You won't get both `John` and `Michael` in the first column.

Comment: @Barmar Your answer was different. This one first generates numbers per age group, and then groups by those row numbers.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I use MySQL, it doesn't have `ROW_NUMBER()` or `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post, but I'm using mysql

Comment: I only get one person per each group

Comment: Yeah, after fixing the syntax errors, it still doesn't seem to work right: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45b6b/25

Comment: @GolezTrol . . . Good work with the SQL Fiddle.  It works now that the typo `@agegroup = agegroup` is fixed to `@agegroup := agegroup`.

Comment: It does. It took me a while to figure out how, but I understand now. Harder to comprehend, but more flexible towards adding more age groups. You've earned your +1. ;)